# Nginx, and mysql timeout - upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, uwsgi

My stack is uWSGI with the gevent loop, flask, mysql, and the python mysql.connector s I can make async mysql queries.  Lateley I have been getting the below error in the nginx logs when i run a query.  Can take upto 60 secs for a query to complete.  Out side of the stack the query works.  When I run using the built in flask dev server locally on my laptop and hit the mysql server halfway around the world..it works.  So..I assume a nginx configuration issue.

```
2013/01/05 01:49:48 [error] 7267#0: *2878 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /ajax_grid?date_from=2013-01-02&date_to=2013-01-04&rt=crpr&a_dhx_rSeed=1357350534901 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:6000", host: "test.com", referrer: "http://test.com/"
```

Below are my relevant options for nginx.  What should I tweak to not get the error?

```
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
keepalive_requests 100000;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
proxy_read_timeout 200;
reset_timedout_connection on;
client_body_timeout 60;
send_timeout 2;
# server_tokens off;
# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

server {
        listen   80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;



    location / {
                   include uwsgi_params;
                   uwsgi_buffering off;
                   #uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   #uwsgi_param Host $http_host;
                   #uwsgi_pass uwsgi_dashboard;
                   uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:6000;
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably need to set [`uwsgi_read_timeout`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule#uwsgi_read_timeout) to extend the time nginx will wait for data from your upstream server.  It's default is 60 seconds.

---

Actually, what you *really* need to do is shift the long-running job into a background/async task, since most *http clients* are unwilling to wait for data from a server for more than 120 seconds; they'll timeout anyway.  use an async processing framework like celery, and allow the client to query a url to find the status of the running job, possibly cancel it, and retrieve it once it's finished.

if you are determined to block your wsgi container, you can use a redirect once the data is complete; and send some sort of content to the client to keep it connected.